# How to change Caffe input image size in prototxt?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I've used Alexnet and Caffe framework, First i save my object images and then resize theme to 100X200 and then I've created LMDB database and read those images and labeled theme to lmdb-file. now i want to train my network using these prototxt:

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    #crop_size: 100
    mean_file: "[my-location]/db/mean.binaryproto"
  }
# mean pixel / channel-wise mean instead of mean image
#  transform_param {
#    crop_size: 227
#    mean_value: 104
#    mean_value: 117
#    mean_value: 123
#    mirror: true
#  }
  data_param {
    source: "[my-location]/db/train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 256
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    #crop_size: 100
    mean_file: "[my-location]/db/mean.binaryproto"
  }
# mean pixel / channel-wise mean instead of mean image
#  transform_param {
#    crop_size: 227
#    mean_value: 104
#    mean_value: 117
#    mean_value: 123
#    mirror: true
#  }
  data_param {
    source: "[my-location]/db/validation_lmdb"
    batch_size: 50
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  ......
```

When i tried to train the network with Caffe script in caffe directory:

```
caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver [solverlocation].prototxt
```

I've got

> data_transformer.cpp:63] Check failed: datum_height ==
>   data_mean_.height() (200 vs. 100)

I know default imagnet images is 100X100, but there is no way my network work with that size. How can i tell Caffe that my input image size(width,height) has changed ?

PS = I've comment out `crop_size` to avoid any change to input images which read from lmdb.

Comment: `data_mean` shape is the least of your problems... Your net has fully-connected layers (`"InnerProduct"`) making it very difficult to change input size...

Comment: Did you create your lmdb and image mean with different sized images?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, no sir. they are all 100X200

Comment: @Shai, is there any guide or hint that i can start with? Are all Networks works with default size?

Comment: @comeymacdonald The error message strongly suggests that this is not the case, so you might want to double check just in case. Also, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35770617/5987698) solves your problem.

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes i tried that before, those RESIZE thing didn't works for me.

Comment: @Shai , I reach the point that fully connected layer tell me `Source param shape is 4096 3072 (12582912); target param shape is 4096 1024 (4194304)` , it is difficult part, how can i fix it , is there any way.